# Neukirch 'Algebraic number theory', p73, Prop 11.6. there is a surjection $Cl(O) \to Cl(O(X))$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, ideal-class-group

This is a question related to Neukirch 'Algebraic number theory',

$p 71$, $Prop 11.6$ ([https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~agboola/teaching/2021/fall/225A/neukirch.pdf](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Eagboola/teaching/2021/fall/225A/neukirch.pdf)).

Let $o$ be a Dedekind domain and let $o(X)=\{\frac{f}{g}\mid f,g \in o, g \not\equiv 0 \pmod p, \forall p \in X\}$.

Neukirhi's 'Algebraic number theory', prop 11.6 reads there is a surjection $Cl(O) \to Cl(O(X))$.

The proof foes as follows.

The map $Cl(O) \to Cl(O(X))$ is  defined as $a \to aO(X)$ and class of prime ideal $p\in X$ goes to class of prime ideal of $O(X)$.

**This class generates $Cl(O(X))$, thus surjection.**

My question is, why $Cl(O(X))$ is **generated by** the image of the prime ideal $p$ of $X$ ?

Comment: See lemma 10.9.16 (last on the page) of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00CM

Comment: Could you elaborate it ?  $S$ is not multiplicative closed set, so I wonder why you can apply lemma about localization.

Comment: $g_1$ and $g_2 \not \in p \implies g_1g_2\not \in p$, so the denominators form a multiplicative set. (and $1\not \in p$ of course)

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: I don't still see how you apply the lemma to this situation. Is it possible to elaborate it to answer form ?

Comment: maybe this evening; I am on the road!

Comment: (hopefully someone else will get to it before then)

Comment: Meanwhile I'm still not sure about what it is your issue here: can you elaborate? Maybe with an example (that will both you and us), e.g., $o=\mathbb Z$, $X$ = all prime ideals except $(2)$ and $(3)$. Then ${\cal O}(X)$ is the subring of the rationals with only powers of $2$ and $3$ allowed in the denominators. Agree?